# Container not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

could you help me?

> I'm trying to run a container by a dockerfile but it shows this
> warning and my container does not start.
>
> compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing:
> <Container: remote-Starting remote-host ... done
>
> compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>
> compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Finished processing: <Service:
> remote_host>
>
> compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
>
> Attaching to jenkinks, remote-host
>
> compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker logs <-
> ('f2e305942e57ce1fe90c2ca94d3d9bbc004155a136594157e41b7a916d1ca7de',
> stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True, follow=True)
>
> remote-host    | Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
> remote-host    | Unable to load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
> remote-host    | Unable to load host key:
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key remote-host    | sshd: no hostkeys
> available -- exiting.
>
> compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events <-
> (filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=jenkins',
> 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']}, decode=True)

My dockerfile is this:

> FROM centos RUN yum -y install openssh-server RUN yum install -y
> passwd RUN useradd remote_user && 
> echo "1234" | passwd remote_user  --stdin && 
> mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && 
> chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh COPY remote_user.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys RUN chown
> remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && 
> chmod 400 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Comment: your notes above are telling you the error ... no hostkeys available ...  dockerfile is just issuing commands you can manually issue yourself ... assure the sequence of commands works when U issue them in a terminal ... then assure those files become visible from inside docker ... its easy enough to troubleshoot that by slimming down the dockerfile to just its first line or two then add new lines to dockerfile only when its working ... when pasting text into a question first put into an editor then select all then tab over  then copy N paste into question ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with an empty dir and put following in that dir as a file called Dockerfile

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server 
RUN yum install -y passwd 
RUN useradd remote_user

RUN echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin 

RUN mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh


RUN chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote_user.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user 

RUN chmod 400 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D


# CMD ["/bin/bash"]


# ... save this file as Dockerfile then in same dir issue following
#
# docker build --tag stens_centos .   # creates image stens_ubuntu
#
# docker run -d  stens_centos  sleep infinity # launches container and just sleeps only purpose here is to keep container running
#
# docker ps     #   show running containers
#
# 
# ... find CONTAINER ID from above and put into something like this
#
# docker exec -ti $( docker ps | grep stens_centos | cut -d' ' -f1 ) bash   #  login to running container
#
```

then in that same dir put your ssh key files as per

```
eve@milan ~/Dropbox/Documents/code/docker/centos $ ls -la
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  2 eve eve  4096 Nov  2 15:20 .
drwx------ 77 eve eve 12288 Nov  2 15:14 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 eve eve   875 Nov  2 15:20 Dockerfile
-rwx------  1 eve eve  3243 Nov  2 15:18 remote_user
-rwx------  1 eve eve   743 Nov  2 15:18 remote_user.pub
```

then cat out Dockerfile and copy and paste commands it explains at bottom of Dockerfile file ... for me all of them just worked OK

after I copy and pasted those commands listed at bottom of Dockerfile the container gets built and executed

```
docker ps
  
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND            CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
0a06ebd2752a   stens_centos   "sleep infinity"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes             pedantic_brahmagupta
```

keep in mind you must define in your Dockerfile the bottom CMD or similar to be just what you want to get executed as the container runs which typically is a server which by definition runs forever ... alternatively this CMD can be simply something which runs then finishes like a batch job in which case the container will exit when that job finishes ... with this knowledge I suggest you confirm `sshd -D` will hold that command as a server or will immediately terminate upon launch of container

Comment: Remember that anyone who has the Docker image can run `docker history` on it, and trivially extract that password.  If you want an interactive debugging shell on the image, `docker run --rm -it image_name bash` is probably easier than the `docker ps`/`docker exec` recipe you show.

Answer (score 0):

I've just replied to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7577#issuecomment-736888259), but here's what I experienced and how I fixed it

I just had this issue for my Jekyll blog site which I normally bring up using docker-compose with mapped volume to rebuild when I create a new post - it was hanging, tried to run `docker-compose up` with  the `--verbose` switch and saw the same `compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()`.

I tried it on my Macbook and it was working fine

I didn't have any experimental features turned on, but I need need to go into (on Windows) settings-> resources -> File Sharing and add the folder I was mapping in my docker compose (the root of my blog site)

Re ran docker compose and its now up and running

Version Info:
[image]